# How to ensure of a referrer to a website?

Tags: http-referer

Can anyone think of a neat solution for this; we operate an website service and sell to large organisations.  Rather than have a logon for everyone, we'd like to be able to provide a  direct link to our website from the organisation's Intranet page.  We'd then like to check the referrer and if it's in our listed of 'trusted referrers', i.e. the intranet url, then we grant logon without asking for credentials.

I'm aware you can do $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; to get the referrer, but I'm also aware that can be spoofed.  Can anyone think of how we could achieve what we want, but while also guaranteeing it won't be hackable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The referrer information comes from the client so it can always be spoofed.

Comment: Yes that's not secure at all, what about the IP address?

Comment: An IP address isn't secure either.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exectly what you want, but to make logging on easier and ensure you don't need to store all the passwords you could use, for example, [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no perfect and safe solution for this.

One solution would be to append tokens to the urls. It will work and it will be save, but anyone who knows the link (including token) will be able to login as that organization

Another solution would be to check the source ip. This can be done in different ways *apache, load balancer, app, etc).

Also a combination of token + ip could work (this token for that organization but only if the request comes from allowed_ips for that organization)

A more elegant solution (which I implemented for several big companies) would be to integrate you website login with the active record domain login. It is possible to use the current user window login as login into a website, using domain authorization.  If a user is logged in into a domain, when enters your site will automatically login to the website.

This solution is much more easy to implement than it sounds. But, requires Active directory and workstation that connects to a domain to be in the company (this shouldn't be a problem, most of corporations are using windows on workstations and active directory for domain controller). Also is working best on IE only (direct login to the website). On other browsers the domain login popup will appear and user will have to enter again the domain password.

Also, I am pretty sure that can be made to work on linux environments, but I have no idea how.